# Firewall management in Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, firewall

I've been trying for hours to block a single port(sql server) from remote access. In linux a single line of iptables command would be enough. In 2008 i couldn't manage to make it happen.

The documentation says that if an exception rule regarding to the port does not exist, the port access will be denied. A rule in Inbound filterse regarding to port 1433 exists, allowing  any ip to connect the service.

- I've changed the allowed ips to local ips
- I've set the rule for all profiles
- I've added an extra  block all rule for port 1433
- I've completely disabled rule to see if "if an exception does not exist, the port will be blocked" is true.

None of the above and another bazillion different settings worked. i still can connect to remote server's 1433th port.I've googled to see if i'm missing something. "windows 2008 firewall block port" were my main keywords. nothing but junk and "tens of pages talking about microft blah but not coming to a point" documents comes up. i've tried "linux firewall block port" to see if i'm searching it wrong,  first two links have the answers. sigh..

anyway, how can i block anyone but the local server from accessing to it's 1433th port on windows server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Won't it work to just double click on that accept rule and change it to "Block the connection"?

Comment: done that, didn't work. tried it on both inbound and outbound rules. clicked "apply", then "ok". i still can access the server's 1433th port.

Comment: just for kicks, when you say you can still "access" the server on port 1433, what exactly are you doing to test this and is there a network firewall between your test box and the server that could be proxying that connection?

Comment: telnet remote_host 1433. i'm not really sure about another proxying host, but i'll ask the hosting firm, and also if they could help with firewall stuff. thanks.